# Best way to keep encryption key secure in Angular application

Tags: angular, encryption

I have an Angular application that I want to encrypt the data before calling the `HttpClient.post()`. I am using [CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/) to encrypt and decrypt data. With the encrypt and decrypt methods, I am required to provide a Secure Passphrase and/or IV values. Currently, I am storing them in the environment.ts. How do I keep the keys safe as anybody can open the developer console to look at these javascript files.

Comment: The premise [is wrong](https://www.nccgroup.com/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/). What you're doing provides no security improvement. Who do you want to protect the key from and why?

Answer (score 0):

Use a lightweight package called "dotenv".
https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/setup-dotenv-to-access-environment-variables-in-angular-9-f06c6ffb86c0
The article does help, but i'll help summarize. environment files are required by Angular for the build process, meaning they have to be pushed to the repository so that others can also install the project locally. If you have your API keys explicitly written in these files, consider those keys compromised, because anyone who has access to your repository can see them.

Edit: oops did not notice that another person has already suggested it before I posted this